# Installing openCV on Lion OS 10.7.4 Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv

I'm trying to install openCV on university's iMac,

but the problem is our university's network is so strict.

and I couldn't install openCV using MacPorts.

I tried google to look for a way to install but it all failed

i guess because it is kind of old ways and because my network is so strict.

So if anybody knows a way that I can download a ready framework with how to use it inside

Xcode. or at least a framework with how to install it to work with Xcode.
or a way to download from the source and compile it then install it in Xcode
please.

Because I tried the cmake way and I still have no luck to get it work.

thanks in advance.

---

sources I used:

http://salemsayed.me/?p=240

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port

http://www.ient.rwth-aachen.de/cms/software/opencv/

Comment: Have you tried Homebrew? It may well have the same issues as MacPorts though! http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: exactly thats why i want a standalone way like downloading installer or something ..

Comment: I managed to install it with Homebrew but I don't know how to get it work with Xcode ... so I can't confirm if the installation is right 100% ....
thanks anyway ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Lion + Xcode 4.x branch, with OpenCV svn trunk. Everything works fine. You have to install **cmake** first, then get the code from the svn following the instructions at http://code.opencv.org . The compilation process worked fine for me for all the core modules + the Qt module + the GPU module + TBB acceleration.

The instructions are the same as the Linux platform.
After setting up cmake configuration in a terminal (using **ccmake** for a more interactive tool),
I set the architecture to **x86_64** (on my MBP Core 2 Duo), the target directory to `/usr/local/`(the default), and I have Intel TBB installed in `/usr/local/`.

Cmake generates the makefiles for you, so you just have to type `make -j2` to compile, then `sudo make install`. If you're working on a workstation, then you have more CPU power, and you can replace the value 2 by more, e.g. 8.

Comment: Actually I managed to install the openCV using homebrew for Mac ..
but how can I make sure that it is installed correctly ?
I want to start working on openCV using Xcode but I don't know if the installation is right ...
if you can tell me what is the steps from the begging to use it with Xcode .. like what kind of project should i choose and how to write a hello world like app to test the openCV .. It would be very helpful.

thanks in advance ..

Comment: To test your installation, create a command line project for C++. Then, in the project settings, add the search path for the header and dylibs (that should be /usr/local/include/ and /usr/local/lib/ respectively). Add also some opencv linker flags under the eponym setting, e.g. -lopencv_core and -lopencv_highgui. In the main.ccp file, include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> and <opencv2/highgui/hihggui.hpp> and try to read, display, save an image.